# Слитно или раздельно "недоступен"?

Tags: орфография

Полный обзор большинства публикаций не доступен с данного неуплаченного доступа.

Comment: А доступ точно именно "неуплаченный"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Вообще-то слитно, но здесь **повтор:**  недоступен и доступ.
2. Можно сказать: обзор **невозможен.**
3. Вероятно, доступ **неоплаченный**, например: https://proza.ru/2015/11/17/2070
4. **НЕДОСТУПНЫЙ**,  2. Недостижимый по каким-л. причинам. Н-ые товары.  Н-ая цена.

Нет смысла без особых причин использовать отрицание, если с задачей вполне справляется утвердительная форма.